# Firebase overwrite existing record

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

With the following code that is used to create a new user into Firebase BaaS, but when it is launched it overwrite the existing user.

```
  let test = Firebase(url: "https://dr-freud.firebaseio.com/users")

     ref.createUser(email.text, password: password.text,
        withValueCompletionBlock: { error, result in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)

             } else {

                let uid = result["uid"] as? String

                let nome = self.nome.text!
                let cognome = self.cognome.text!

                let utente = ["Nome": nome, "Cognome": cognome]

                let users = ["\(self.nome.text!)": utente]

                test.setValue(users)

            }
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `setValue()` on the same location, so you'll indeed overwrite the existing data at that location.

To prevent this, you'll need to call `setValue()` on a user-specific location:

```
let currentUser = test.childByAppendingPath(uid)
currentUser.setValue(users)
```

By calling `childByAppendingPath()` we end up with a reference to a database location that is specific to this user.

This and much more is covered in [Firebase's programming guide for iOS](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/). I *highly* recommend that you spend some time in that guide. A few hours there will save you many problems and questions down the line.

Comment: I appreciate company that have engineer at StackOverflow to help developer. Thank you, I'm new in Firebase .

Answer (score 2):

It's overwriting due to this line

```
test.setValue(users)
```

You need to create a separate child for each user that you write to the users node.

Since this is the users node, you should use the uid that the createUser provides. Frank's answer is correct so the below is more of a general case answer.

If it was some other node where you are not provided a natural key, using autoId will help you do this; here's an example.

```
let pizzaRef = ref.childByAppendingPath("pizzas")
let thisPizzaRef = pizzaRef.childByAutoId()
let pizzaData = ["crustType": "Thick"]
thisPizzaRef.setValue(pizzaData)
```

this will create a new node within the users node each time it's called

```
pizzas
  -J1092uf8n0293i
     crustType: "Thick"
  -J989jijsoissds
     crustType: "Thick"
```

Comment: Lol. For sure! I think both answers are valid so we'll roll with it.

Comment: In general, if an entity has a natural key, store it under that natural key. We get too many questions already from developers who stored their users under a push id and then end up querying for them by uid all the time. So while I welcome your answer, I think mine is better (in this specific case). :-p

Comment: Mind you: I still **highly** appreciate the stellar job you're doing helping developers new to Firebase. You were already invaluable. But your Parse and iOS experience is even more needed recently. If you reach out to me at puf-at-firebase-dot-com, I'd love to send some Firebase swag your way!

Comment: Oh my. You are totally correct. Even though i typed it, I overlooked that the it's the *USERS* node we are talking about and of course it has a natural key so that should definitely be used instead of the autoId. I updated my answer to also address nodes other than the users node.